# MySQL installed but nowhere to be found on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, mysql

I installed MySQL 5.7 using homebrew:

```
brew install mysql@5.7
```

As I understand, I am supposed to find mysql in /usr/local or /usr/local/bin but I see that mysql@5.7 was placed in /usr/local/opt.

So I tried adding that to the path:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

But still when I try to type mysql or mysql@5.7 in the terminal it says "command not found".

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get mysql to become available as a terminal command?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqlsh` in the terminal works for me. I installed the MySQL Community Server and MySQL Shell from Oracle's binaries. I don't know if this is different when installed from the homebrew repositories.

I also had to add `/usr/local/mysql/bin` to `/etc/paths` and now the `mysql` command by itself works as well from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago and I am still using the full path each time but the easiest way to add a new path to $PATH (the environment variable) is with the export command. In this example we’ll add “~/opt/bin” to the user PATH with export:

export PATH=$PATH:~/opt/bin

See the following for further details:

http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/14/add-new-path-to-path-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Force link 5.7 version - `$ brew link mysql@5.7 --force`

Now you can verify the installed MySQL instance : `$ mysql -V`.